# How should I use "thus" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I am wondering if any of these following sentences is correct. If so, what is the most common way to say it in an academic context?

1. **They can thus take advantage of this technology...**
2. **They thus can take advantage of this technology...**
3. **Thus they can take advantage of this technology...**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You forgot 3. **Thus they can take advantage of this technology** and 4. **Thus can they take advantage of this technology**

Comment: It depends on what you want to emphasise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form "thus can" is not exactly grammatically incorrect, but that is not the optimal position of the adverb.

When an adverb is placed next to verbs, it:

1. follows an auxiliary or modal verb if there is one;
2. a verb be; or
3. precedes the main verb, in that order,

as shown [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position).

Comment: So... Would be "they can thus take..." the most correct one, based on that information?

Comment: Yes, of course.